# jquery get each checked and get value from data attribute into array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have tag html like these

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chekship" data-kp="NORT180606" data-po="4000779848" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="chekship" data-kp="NORT180607" data-po="4000776985" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="chekship" data-kp="NORT180707" data-po="4000777001" checked>
```

And problem is when i try push array with these code

```
$('.chekship:checked').each(function() {
                data.push($(this).data("kp"),$(this).data("po"));       
            });
```

the result i get is

```
array(6) {
[0]=>
  string(10) "NORT180606"
[1]=>
  string(10) "4000779848"
[2]=>
  string(10) "NORT180607"
[3]=>
  string(10) "4000776985"
[4]=>
  string(10) "NORT180707"
[5]=>
  string(10) "4000777001"
}
```

what i need this array separated base on input like these

```
 [0]=>
       [0]=>
      string(10) "NORT180606"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "4000779848"
[1]=>
       [0]=>
      string(10) "NORT180607"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "4000776985"
[2]=>
       [0]=>
      string(10) "NORT180707"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "4000777001"
```

How do i do that?? Is kinda confusing me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just push an *array* to `data`, rather than passing two separate parameters to `push` (which will add two separate items to the array):

```
$('.chekship:checked').each(function() {
  data.push([
    $(this).data("kp"),
    $(this).data("po")
  ]);
});
```

`.map` might be a bit more appropriate than `.each` though, since you're creating a new array for every item in the match:

```
const data = $('.chekship:checked')
  .map(function() {
    return [
      $(this).data("kp"),
      $(this).data("po")
    ];
  })
  .get();
```

or, no need for a big library like jQuery at all for something this simple:

```
const data = Array.prototype.map.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.chekship:checked'),
  ({ dataset: { kp, po } }) => [kp, po]
);
```

Comment: That's exactly i wanted!!! Tq so much!! Sorry i cant approve your answer need more 8 minute to approced

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = $('.chekship:checked');

const resultArr = Array.prototype.map.call(data, function(ele) {
        return [ele.getAttribute('data-kp'), ele.getAttribute('data-po')];
});

console.log(resultArr);
```